# What is the $ in Syntactic sugar of Java?

Tags: java, jvm

```
//source code 
int[] s = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
for(int i:s){
    System.out.println(i);
}
----------------------------
//below is in the class file 
for(int i$ = 0; i$ < b; ++i$) {
    int i = a[i$];
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

what's the use of the $?  i$ is a pointer like c?

Comment: What do you mean _"... is in the class file"_? The class file does not contain Java code, it contains binary bytecodes.

Comment: The class file does not contain any variable names. The name "i$" was generated by the decompiler you're using. Other decompilers could generate any other names for that variable.

Comment: Nothing special about currency symbols. You can just use `$` as a variable if you wish.

Comment: `$` doesn't have a special meaning in C either. You can have operators `*` or `&` but not `$`

Comment: BTW My "faviourite" random character to use in a variable is `\u202e` which is zero width and causes all the letters after it to appear right to left (as in Arabic and Hebrew)

Answer (score 5):

In this case, it is literally a variable named `i$`. [JLS-3.8. Identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) reads (in part)

> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters A-Z (`\u0041`-`\u005a`), and a-z (`\u0061`-`\u007a`), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (`_`, or `\u005f`) and dollar sign (`$`, or `\u0024`). The `$` sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.

Comment: Note: as `$` is allowed, so are all the other currency symbols such as `£` and `€` are allowed. There is actually 10 continuation characters including `_` To avoid confusion with some other languages `_` alone is not allowed for lambda parameters but can be used for other variables. o_O

Comment: Interesting note about `$` should only be used for generated code. Good advice, but I didn't realise it was in the spec +1.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: should be noted that a sole underscore as identifier is not only forbidden for lambda parameters, but also deprecated for all other use cases and will be forbidden in general in Java 9.

Comment: @Holger Thank you +1.  Any reason sole $ is not given it is specifically mentioned as to be avoided (or is it)?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Mostly, because [there are intentions for using `_` for language features](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-July/010670.html) whereas there are apparently no such plans for `$`. The state of the sole dollar still is the same as for any identifier containing a dollar, you shouldn’t use it (as already cited in this answer).

Comment: @Holger of course you can use `_` now for catch variable which isn't used though I prefer `ignored`

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: when you use `_` for a variable now, you’ll get a warning about the discouraged identifier, but still can access it. I guess, the intention is that in a future language, naming the variable `_` does not add it to the scope, i.e. you can not access it, but in turn, can do that multiple times, e.g. `(_, _) -> {…}` would be a lambda expression ignoring both parameters…

Comment: @Holger I agree this is most likely the intended use case. I am not sure it is really that valuable as it adds subtle complexity to the language. Once you understand what it us doing it might be useful in rare cases but I expect there will be many duplicate SO questions on it.